# Modify video quality of Cordova Capture plugin on IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, video, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to record a low quality video with an app using Cordova and the plugin Capture because I need to upload on a server a lot of videos.

I have tried to put inside options parameter 'height' and 'width' values, but it doesn't work. So during a long search on the web I have found this plugin: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/VideoCapturePlus-PhoneGap-Plugin/tree/1dabebe06cc5482a4574b800508a91230e25591b that is great but it doesn't provide any possibility of configuration. I need of the possibility to set through height and width parameters my video quality.

So, anyone knows how to do it?

Thanks folk!

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert it with videoEditor plugin.

Answer (score -3):

Have you considered "faking" it by hiding a portion of the recorded video with HTML/CSS to the exact width/height that you need?